# Which SUB is calling this SUB

Tags: vba, ms-access

Does anyone out there know how to do a stack trace in [access-vba](/questions/tagged/access-vba). I'm trying to do  something like:

```
Public Sub a()   
    Call c    
End Sub    

Public Sub b()    
    Call c    
End Sub

Public Sub c()    
    Debug.Print "Which sub has called me ?"    
End Sub
```

What I want to do in `Sub c` is to show if that has been called by `Sub a` or `Sub b` without passing any arguments. In [c](/questions/tagged/c) I would simply show the stack but I have no idea if this is even possible in VBA - any thoughts ?

Comment: can you explain why you require this...?

Comment: I have some code in a form that calls a function. At the start of the function I write to a log file to say that function has started. From one of my users I can see this function being called whilst it is already running. What I'm trying to see is if this is really the case or if the logging is not working.

Comment: place logging in SUB a, b and c ...

Comment: I have that but it doesn't explain why a function is called twice on Access 2007 / 2010 but on Access 2003 it is only called once. This only happens when you close the database

Comment: I recommend using F8 to step thru your code one line at a time.  It'll highlight each line of code before it is run, so you can see exactly when it jumps to c().

Comment: Using debug doesn't help as the issue is not happening on any of our development or test machines just 2 of the 10 users machine which are all setup the same as far as I can see. All I want to do dump the stack to a log table in sql server,

Answer (score 14):

You can access the call stack during runtime under the menu `View` -> `Call Stack`

Alternatively you can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> during runtime.

[image]

Comment: Hadn't spotted that. This helps but any ideas how I make teh stack call in code ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Mztools Addins which has an option to view the procedure caller.
[Download Mztools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this utility solves the OP's problem, but this is a terrific tool that I discovered from your answer.

Comment: @hungryhippo  Yeah actually and it's my favourite addin for VBA,

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could tell would be to get the return address pointer of the calling subroutine from the stack.  VBA wouldn't do that directly, you would have to have written your own library or have a library from someone else who needed to know these things.  This might be worthwhile if the calling routines are from a program you can't update, however if this is only coming from your own code, it's far easier to rewrite your code to identify the caller.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is by having a ProcedureEnter and ProcedureExit call at the beginning and end of each VBA routine I have.  The ProcedureEnter routine has an argument for the Sub/Function name, which gets stored in a global call stack collection.  ProcedureExit just pops the last entry off the stack.

So, to get the caller routine name, you would just get the item at the Stack Collection .count - 1

I personally use MZTools to set up a default VBA routine header/footer, so that I just type

```
Function fnname(arg as whatever) as boolean
End Function
```

and click the Add Error Handler button in MZTools and it adds the ProcedureEnter and ProcedureExit calls for me.  That makes it a lot less cumbersome to add the stack trace code.