# Can I find what sub is calling a function?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a rather large VBA project and now I need to know what sub is calling the function.

example:

```
sub first()
    RunSomeCode
end sub

sub second()
    RunSomeCode
end sub


Function RunSomeCode()
    ' here I need to know if the calling sub is first() or second()

end function
```

The only way I know of is to pass a string with the functioncall in first and second sub with the calling sub name.
But this function is called from everywhere and I wanted to know if there is a simpler way to do it.

I need to get a string of what sub called the RunSomeCode, to just get it in debugging is not enough.

Comment: Did you try using call stack under View menu ?

Comment: Do you need it when debugging then Imran is right you should use the call stack. If you need it during run time then possibly what you suggested is the way to go and you just add the second parameter as optional. That means only in case `first` or `second` call `RunSomeCode` you will pass the parameter. But anyway, I think this is an [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and you should give some context why you really need this resp. what your real problem is.

Comment: I need it in runtime. I need to know what function has called the `RunSomeCode` and I need it because I need to log it. The problem is I don't want to browse through 10.000 lines of code and add a call parameter on each `RunSomeCode`.

Comment: Why would you need to log it? Because of Errorhandling? And do you need it only for first and second?

Comment: No, Usage statistics. Well.. first and second is actually probably 50 different subs and functions.

Comment: During run time I do not really another solution as somehow to store the information which sub called which one but maybe there is a way I am not aware of.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://etutorials.org/Microsoft+Products/access/Chapter+7.+VBA/Recipe+7.2+Create+a+Global+Procedure+Stack/) is what you need but I am not sure if this is really what you want to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which SUB is calling this SUB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038940/which-sub-is-calling-this-sub)

Comment: @QHarr That is not a duplicate. That only talks about in debug. I need it in running code.

Comment: @Storax Yes, that looks like what I need but to use it it seems to be as much work as to just add a parameter on each function call.

Comment: But  _you can always keep track of the current procedure and the procedure calls that got you there._

Comment: @Storax I know. But if you look at "figure 7.2" and the four grey boxes at the bottom you see that you need to "pushstack" and "popstack" in each function/sub. That means two lines of code per function/sub. Just adding the string as your answer is technically zero lines but it still has to be done manually.

Comment: It covers more than just call stack. See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17048597/6241235). The question itself is a duplicate in terms of what it is asking i.e. _How do I show a string representing the caller in the callee?_ Whether the answers are sufficient is a different matter. Hence why I consider it a potential duplicate.

Comment: I did not say it's for free ;-) It's up to you if it's worth the work in order to get what you want. Or you go for the solution "only" to adapt these 50 sub which call your function.

Comment: @QHarr I believe you are incorrect. The reason why you close vote a question is because you find **an answer** suitable to the question, not because you managed to find a duplicate title or title words say the same. If you only match words from titles then I believe your close votes privilage should be revoked.

Comment: @Andreas, this SO answer could give you some ideas [Is there a way to track which Sub have been run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48081634/is-there-a-way-to-track-which-sub-have-been-run/48102460#48102460)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to track which Sub have been run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48081634/is-there-a-way-to-track-which-sub-have-been-run)

Comment: @Andreas - Technically speaking, you're incorrect. *"Questions should be closed by casting close votes if they are sufficiently similar to existing **question**s and **would be** answered identically to them."* [source](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) (even if there are no answers.) The VTC is not called "Duplicate Answer", it's called "Duplicate Question". I see multiple questions (with answers) that would work - or at least, seem like they would based on the limited information you've provided in the question. I agree with QHarr & Storax - this smells like an XY Problem.

Comment: @ashleedawg You seem to have missed the *answered identically*. Debug and running code is not the same. I understand that it's easier to just say it's a xy problem. But I have given enough reason to say it's not the same question and it's not a xy problem. But it's the same thing every time someone does not understand the question. It has to be xy. It can't be anything else. Right? If I write the full explenation the question will be a wall of text and closed for unclear or too broad. I did what is expected, a MVCE. But you know what? I will type it all out and let you read it.

Comment: As I have written it’s a very large VBA project. It has about 10.000 lines of code and is the gear between five different IT systems. We are currently moving from one IT system to another (and some more), half way through we stopped because it wouldn’t work. We can’t roll back what was moved so we are currently using both. All actions done in one has to be mirrored in the other. And that is where this VBA project comes in, it translates import files from one to the other, making them go hand in hand.

Comment: The file is locked down, write protected and has user accounts and passwords to make sure unauthorized are not using the file. This is as you may understand a very complex VBA project. If “stuff” is not done in the correct order it will fail. Every time I use it it works, but when others use it they say they do one thing and it fails, but error messages and/or outputs show they are doing something wrong. This is where we are now. So how to solve it?

Comment: I want to add a “Google analytics” to the VBA project logging who, when, where and what people are doing and what basic data is loaded so that I can follow it and show them where they did wrong. If I know what code called “RunSomeCode” it will be enough for me to do some logging. If all this would have been added to the question it would have been too broad don’t you think? Is it still a xy-problem?

Comment: @Andreas - You seem to have missed the *"would be"*. From an OP's point of view, their issue is never an XY Problem, it's by nature hard to see from the coder's point of view. An XY Problem is not "one thing" - but solving one is simply an opportunity to take a step back and look at the "big picture" of your project/task to consider the possibility that, just maybe, a previous step could have been handled differently, to prevent the current issue. However you elude inquiries and are argumentative with multiple people trying to help you, which is contradictive to problem solving. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

`Ctrl+L` is the shortcut for the Call Stack in VBA. You may see the stack. As you see in the screenshot below, the function was called from the `Sub Second`:

[image]

Comment: @Andreas - an easy way I can think of is to write `debug.print NAME-OF-SUB/FUNCTION` at the end of each `sub/function`, run the program and examine the results. Thus you would see the order they are being called.

Comment: Not sure I understand what that will do. You mean I shoud add `debug.print "first"` in the code?

Comment: @Andreas - pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only need it in First and Second then probably this could help

```
Option Explicit
Sub first()
    RunSomeCode "First"
End Sub

Sub second()
    RunSomeCode "Second"
End Sub

Sub third()
    RunSomeCode
End Sub

Function RunSomeCode(Optional Caller As String)
' here I need to know if the calling sub is first() or second()
    If Len(Caller) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print Caller
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: This is what I believe I need to do. But not what I want to do. I just assumed there was a way to "extract" the information from "Watches" window. If you add a "Watch" on a variable you will be able to see the function it's running in, if I only could get that line of text. That would solve it all.

Comment: As writtten above if that's possible then I do not know how but maybe others do

Comment: Maybe [this](http://etutorials.org/Microsoft+Products/access/Chapter+7.+VBA/Recipe+7.2+Create+a+Global+Procedure+Stack/) is what you need but I am not sure if this is really what you want to do